# European Tour Groups that Allow Unaccompanied Minors

Tags: legal, europe, tours, minors

Next summer I'll be 16 and my cousin will be 18. We are interested in a tour group about 2 weeks long that's traveling through general Europe. It's difficult finding a travel group that will allow us to go. Are there any reliable and cheap tour groups that we will be allowed to participate in?

Answer (score 1):

Most commerical tours require minors to be accompanied by a parent or legal guardian.  It is due in part to liability reasons. And in part to discipline issues, since a tour guide can not discipline a minor, so they need a guardian onhand to effect control or take the minor off the tour.